# winRT Data Visualization: Getting memory exception after adding source code in my app project

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

After adding reference of winRT xaml data visualization source code in my universal app. when chart plotting with multiple series and large number of data points. app starts crashing and reporting low memory exception.

see the image [image]
Please guide.

thnx.

Comment: Have you tried using the profiler?

Comment: yes i try with profiler and it is showing maximum memory consumption is appear while data point plotted over chart. application start crashing after data points increased from 3000 points. i am using chart to plot multiple series at a time but not more then 10 series and each series may contain 2000 data points at a time.

Comment: The profiler should show you who is using the most memory; is it your data structures or is it the UI? How much total memory are you using?

Comment: yes it is UI(data point presentation). i am not taking any memory. after passing data point whole memory taking by data points only.